# How to use Azure Active Directory with Nuget on Mac

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017, azure-active-directory

In Window 10, normally when you load Visual Studio, a window will pop up if any of the Nuget feeds require authentication via Azure Active Directory.

However, on a Mac when you use Visual Studio (Xamarin) this doesn't occur.  A window pops up asking for credentials, but it's not the same as the third party Azure Active Directory login window.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 on 2 ASP.Net Core project.

Comment: Just to clarify you are using Visual Studio for Mac? Not Visual Studio on Windows running in say parallels on the Mac? There is no explicit support for custom authentication against Azure Active Directory in Visual Studio for Mac beyond what the NuGet library being used supports. What dialog is displayed on Windows?

Comment: Using visual studio code.  On visual studio on mac I figured out how to just add the personal access token with leaving the username blank or whatever you want and use the access token you get from Vso.  On window on window is a pop up web view with third party aad. On mac it's just a username password box .

I'm guessing you can configure the nuget.config to account for these credentials. I still need to figure that aspect out.